# How to create lists from data frames in python

Tags: python, r

My mock up data frame like...

```
data<-structure(list(rno = 1:8, channel = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("AAAA", "BBBB"), class = "factor")), .Names =     c("rno", 
"channel"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Now I wrote a simple code to create dummy variables in R.

```
chan_names<-sort(as.character(unique(data[,"channel"])))
data10<-list()
for(i in 1:length(chan_names))
{
    data10[[i]]<-data[,"channel"]==chan_names[i]
}
data10<-do.call("cbind",data10)
colnames(data10)<-chan_names
```

Now I want to do same operation in python. I am beginner in python. help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/),

```
import pandas as pd

cats = pd.Categorical((1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), (1L, 2L))
cats.categories = ('AAAA', 'BBBB')
data = pd.DataFrame({'rno': np.arange(1,9), 'channel': cats})
#   channel  rno
# 0    AAAA    1
# 1    BBBB    2
# 2    AAAA    3
# 3    AAAA    4
# 4    BBBB    5
# 5    BBBB    6
# 6    BBBB    7
# 7    AAAA    8

data10 = pd.get_dummies(data['channel']).astype(bool)
```

yields

```
    AAAA   BBBB
0   True  False
1  False   True
2   True  False
3   True  False
4  False   True
5  False   True
6  False   True
7   True  False
```

Comment: Hi unutbu, can u look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296113/how-to-use-dcast-function-to-transform-my-dataset

Comment: I've looked. What is the problem?